# Difference between Europol members and Europol cooperating countries

Tags: international, european-union, corporate-law

According to Europol, they are actually 28 members in this organization but also numbers of others [external co-operating countries](https://www.europol.europa.eu/content/page/external-cooperation-31) like Switzerland, Norway and even USA

So, what the point of being not members of Europol but [cooperating](https://www.europol.europa.eu/latest_news/europol-signs-cooperation-agreement-liechtenstein) with them anyway ?

- Are there any differences between Europeans cooperating countries and non Europeans one like USA or Colombia ?
- Are non-Europol members countries more sovereign than members of Europol ?
- Are they any difference in intelligence sharing between members and non-members ?

Comment: Switzerland and Norway are not a part of the European Union, and the US is obviously not a part of the EU. So that may be a factor for membership. Cooperating with them just means that those countries recognize the validity and authority of their actions.

Comment: "Members" refers to "members of the EU", not "members of Europol": Europol is the EU law enforcement agency.